# How to iterate into components inside a TTabSheet

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I'm trying to iterate between all components inside a `TTabsheet`. Problem is, inside this tab there are only a memo and a edit, but my code iterate between components in all form. What am I'm missing ?

```
var i : integer;
begin
with PageControl1.ActivePage do 
 for i := 0 to componentcount-1 do
   begin
   // componentcount should be 2, but actually is 95
   components[i].doSomething;
   end;
end;
```

Comment: That means somehow your tabsheet owns the components on your form. In any case, you don't want to iterate components - components are not inside components. Controls are. You want to iterate controls.

Comment: Very strange that your tabsheet owns so many components which would normally be owned by the form. Or more likely you posted fake code. Use ControlCount and Controls[] to walk the parent/child structure. Be prepared to recurse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had something like this, where a button click caused code to traverse over all the controls that were on a tabsheet that was on a page control, using the components array. Later on I changed it to the following, that uses the controls array of the given tabsheet.

```
procedure TShowDocsByRank.CleanBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
 i: integer;

begin
 for i:= 0 to tabsheet1.controlcount - 1 do
  if tabsheet1.controls[i] is TLabeledEdit
   then TLabeledEdit (tabsheet1.controls[i]).text:= ''
  else if tabsheet1.controls[i] is TComboBox
   then TComboBox (tabsheet1.controls[i]).text:= '-';
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps 'with' might have something to do about it. You cant really tell what the return value for 'componentcount' will be (might even return number of components for the form itself?).